# Plotting different dataframe data in subplots

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm trying to plot data in two dataframes in two subplots. I'm referring to [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13/visualization.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))


plt.figure()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

df1.plot(ax=axes[0, 0], style='o-')
axes[0, 0].set_xlabel('x')
axes[0, 0].set_ylabel('y')
axes[0, 0].set_title('ttl')

df2.plot(ax=axes[0, 1], style='o-')
axes[0, 1].set_xlabel('x')
axes[0, 1].set_ylabel('y')
axes[0, 1].set_title('ttl')
```

However, I get the following error

```
df1.plot(ax=axes[0, 0], style='o-')
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this will be really helpful.
EDIT: The answer provided below works for 1 row with 2 cols

I'm facing an error for 2 rows and 2 cols

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))

pprint(df1)

plt.figure()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

df1.plot(ax=axes[0], style='o-')
axes[0].set_xlabel('x')
axes[0].set_ylabel('y')
axes[0].set_title('ttl')

df2.plot(ax=axes[1], style='o-')
axes[1].set_xlabel('x')
axes[1].set_ylabel('y')
axes[1].set_title('ttl')


df3.plot(ax=axes[2], style='o-')
axes[2].set_xlabel('x')
axes[2].set_ylabel('y')
axes[2].set_title('ttl')

df4.plot(ax=axes[3], style='o-')
axes[3].set_xlabel('x')
axes[3].set_ylabel('y')
axes[3].set_title('ttl')

plt.show()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axes are one dimensional, you have to do like this:

```
df1.plot(ax=axes[0], style='o-')
df2.plot(ax=axes[1], style='o-')
```

I suggest reading [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html), look at the squeeze parameter and you will understand this is happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Could you please check my edit?

Comment: I think you are missing how to use pandas to plot data, I suggest reading this: https://datatofish.com/plot-dataframe-pandas/

Comment: The error occurs in line 17 when plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2). It works for plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2). I looked at the reference you provided, it's used for plotting dataframe columns. please let me know if I am missing something

Comment: In that case, axes is 2 dimensional and thus you have to do axes[i][j] i=0,1 j=0,1 @Natasha